# How to create a slideshow with navigation button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code block to acheive a slideshow to navigate different content(list) on click of the navigation buttons. Everything goes fine and works great. But indeed i need an additional feature like the slideshow should run on the load of the page and the buttons to choose the exact position of the slideshow as well. Still I need those button to navigate my slide show. Thanks in advance.

**MARKUP**

```
<div class="testimony">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="test-con">
            <li class="current">
               <a class="image-frame" href="">
               <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/150"></a>
               <h5>“ My Test Content 1 ”</h5>
               <h6>- Test 1</h6>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a class="image-frame" href="">
               <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/150"></a>
               <h5>“My Test Content 2”</h5>
               <h6>- Test 2</h6>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a class="image-frame" href="">
               <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/150"></a>
               <h5>“ My Test Content 2 ”</h5>
               <h6>- Test 3</h6>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navigator">
            <li class="current"></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.navigator li').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
    $('.test-con li').hide();
    $('.test-con li').eq(index).addClass('current').fadeIn('slow').siblings().removeClass('current');
});
```

NOTE: Need to animate `width` instead of **fade animation**.

FOR REFERENCE: **[CHECK THIS](http://bxslider.com/examples/auto-show-start-stop-controls)**

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/8syd2e3f/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryUI provides a lot of facilities to make personalized the js code.
In any case, why don't you try to use a library of js sliders already existing?

What you want to create could increase proportionally with the appeal you want to reach :)
I knew http://www.slidesjs.com/, which makes the same work with the required attention.

Alex